# Placing columns in new lines while adding information from previous lines

Tags: bash, awk

I want to reduce the number of columns in my file to 3, by placing all columns beyond column #3 into new lines and have those strings preceded by the column #1 and #2 values from the previous line. This is a bit abstract so here is an example:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
A4 B4 C4
```

turn into

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A2 B2 D2
A3 B3 C3
A3 B3 D3
A3 B3 E3
A4 B4 C4
```

Each `Cn`, `Dn`, and `En` value needs the information of `An` and `Bn`.

I found the solution to the first part of my problem here:
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/125202-awk-new-line-between-columns.html

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3"\n"$4"\n"$5}' oldfile > newfile
```

this yields

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A1 B1 C1


A2 B2 C2
D2

A3 B3 C3
D3
E3
A4 B4 C4
```

So `An` and `Bn` are missing for the moved strings. Unfortunately a bunch of empty new lines is generated as well, they can either be rid of in an extra step, or in the same process, I don't care about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $2, $i}' ip.txt
Column1 Column2 Column3
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A2 B2 D2
A3 B3 C3
A3 B3 D3
A3 B3 E3
A4 B4 C4
```

- `for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)` the variable `i` will start from `3` and loop until `NF` (number of fields)
- `print $1, $2, $i` always print first and second fields and then the field based on variable `i`

Answer (score 1):

A version that do not use loop, but not flexible if number of column increases.

```
awk '{s=$1FS$2;print s,$3 ($4?"\n"s FS$4:"") ($5?"\n"s FS$5:"")}' file
Column1 Column2 Column3
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A2 B2 D2
A3 B3 C3
A3 B3 D3
A3 B3 E3
A4 B4 C4
```